# htaccess redirect difference folder and url in folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

How i can config .htaccess like below:

Redirect "frontend" page to 404 page and redirect all url ( all file) in that "frontend" to "cms" folder:

ex: Redirect like below:

```
http://domain.com/frontend   -> to 404 page
```

and:

```
http://domain.com/frontend/page1.php  -> to: http://domain.com/cms/page1.php
http://domain.com/frontend/page2.php  -> to: http://domain.com/cms/page2.php
.....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteMatch ^/frontend/?$ /path/to/404/page.php
RewriteMatch ^/frontend/(.*) /cms/$1
```

Comment: It work! Thank you, but i use "RedirectMatch 301 " instead of "RewriteMatch". ^^